# Serializing dates in moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a calendar which is initialized this way:

```
  startDate: moment().subtract('month', 1).startOf('month'),
  endDate: moment()
  }, function(start, end) { // on date change - save it and retrieve later
     // start is the start date
     // end is the end date
  }
```

I want to be able to save and restore the start and end dates. As you can see startDate and endDate must be in "moment". I can store it to a cookie or on the server - that doesn't matter.

My question is how to serialize the dates and then restore?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Best solution is to store as milliseconds since epoch...

```
var ms = moment().valueOf();
```

...then you can easily restore by passing that value into the moment constructor...

```
var dt = moment(ms);
```

Comment: Did you mean `start.valueOf()` and `end.valueOf()`?

Comment: I was trying to be more generic, but yes, to store the values you would use `start.valueOf()` and `end.valueOf()` and to restore them you would do `start = moment(storedStartVal)` and `end = moment(storedEndVal)`